# After applying ingress for k8s, why service address was set to node's IP address?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

After applying `ingress` in `k8s`, I see service address was set to `node's` IP address?

**Firstly, I added ingress controller**

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.48.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

**Secondly, I add ingress yml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "n1.avocado.work"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: node1
            port:
              number: 80
```

**Then I checked the ingress:**

```
kubectl get ingress minimal-ingress1
```

The address was the node's IP, Why it's not the master's IP

I tried so many times, all the same result. How can I fix that? Any leads, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on bare metal, this is as per design.  check [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) for more info.

> MetalLB provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes
> clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively
> allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster.
>
> This section demonstrates how to use the Layer 2 configuration mode of
> MetalLB together with the NGINX Ingress controller in a Kubernetes
> cluster that has publicly accessible nodes. In this mode, **one node
> attracts all the traffic for the ingress-nginx Service IP**. See
> Traffic policies for more details.